# Save Whole System

Tags: linux

Is there a way to simply save a whole configurated system ?

I have both a Windows and a Linux installed, both with software configured.
I'd like to be able to "save it" so that when it crashed for a reason or another, or when I want to reinstall it, I could do it very fast.

I've thought about dd-ing the whole stuff in a proper format to avoid using Gigabytes of space, but I don't know if it is the best idea ...
It could work, but then, how can I get my Boot with both OSes back ?

Can I make some sort of "restoration disks" that I could apply back to restore the system ?

Comment: Hi xhaltar. We work differently here compared to a forum that you may be used to. If you have an additional question, you should ask that as a new question (use the "ask question" button near the top right). Include a link to this question if you feel it helps provide context, but try to make sure the new question can stand on its own. By keeping each question posted about a single problem, answerers can focus on that specific question and propose solutions that will help with *that* problem. It also makes it easier for the community to judge which answers are good, helping curate knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do an image with clonezilla. it has the option to do the entire disk as one image including any boot sector stuff. (Read the options when doing it though. I am not sure if boot sector and such is selected by default.)

Comment: +1 - Clonezilla has saved my bacon a number of times, and has gotten much easier to use over the years.

Comment: Okay, then, pardon me to ask another question, but how do you get an ".iso" file with CloneZilla ?

Comment: http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=stable